# Making use of JSON returned from serverside to clientside

Tags: json, jquery

**UPDATE 3:**

The following does not seem to make any difference, does exactly the same thing as the script in update 2:

```
var $obj = jQuery.parseJSON(results);

$.each($obj, function(key, value) { 
    alert(key + " - " + value);
});
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
$.each(jQuery.parseJSON(results), function(key, value) { 
    alert(key + " - " + value);
});
```

The script above is now returning the currect number of alerts, but not the correct data.  it gives me this:

```
0 - [object, Object]
1 - [object, Object]
2 - [object, Object]
```

**UPDATE 1:**

The `get_json.aspx` is currently returning this:

```
[{"key":1,"value":"Default"},{"key":2,"value":"Reports"},{"key":3,"value":"Other"}]
```

The current script now looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get_json.aspx',
    type: 'GET',
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert('Error: ' + status + '\nError Text: ' + error + '\nResponse Text: ' + xhr.responseText);
    },
    success: function(results) {
        $.each(results, function(key, value) { 
            alert(key + " - " + value);
        });
    }
});
```

But when I go to this webpage, it just gives me a never ending supply of javascript alerts, i.e.

```
    0 - undefined
    1 - undefined
    2 - undefined
    3 - undefined
...
    75 - undefined
    76 - undefined
    77 - undefined
    78 - undefined
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

If I return key:value paired JSON from the server.  How do I make use of that JSON?

I am trying to use the JSON in the success part of the ajax/jquery below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'get_json.aspx',
    type: 'GET',
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        alert('Error: ' + status + '\nError Text: ' + error + '\nResponse Text: ' + xhr.responseText);
    },
    success: function(results) {
    /*
    using the key:value pair json return, if 3 pairs are return, somehow generate the following
    where key = the value of the querystring in the url, i.e. tab = 1,2,3
    and value = Default, Reports, Other
        $("#tabs").tabs("add","tabs.aspx?tab=1","Default")
        $("#tabs").tabs("add","tabs.aspx?tab=2","Reports")
        $("#tabs").tabs("add","tabs.aspx?tab=3","Other")
    */
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: I've already returned the json above, I don't know how to use it in jquery.

Comment: Did you read the whole document? You have to parse the JSON string into javascript object. The best way to do that is using JSON.parse from the link I gave you because eval() its not safe.

Comment: results is a simple string. You have to parse it and make a javascript object out of it. So take json_parse.js from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js and then include it in your site. Then you do this:

    `res = JSON.parse(results);`

Then $.each(res...

Comment: Make separate variable for the results object and then use that variable in the each loop.

`var res = jQuery.parseJSON(results); $.each(res...` That should work.

Comment: Please see update 3 as that does not seem to make a difference.

Comment: I'm sorry. I see it now. Take out the '[]' brackets. If it doesn't work I have another solution for you.

Comment: Done that, and now it is only returning the last secton of the json data i.e. it returns 2 alert boxes. the first one shows "key - 3" and the second one shows "value - other".

Comment: `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(results);

var len = obj.length;

for(i=0; i<len; i++) { 
    alert(obj[i].key + " - " + obj[i].value);
});`

Comment: I'm now getting a blank screen with no alerts at all.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have syntax error. `+ obj[i].value); });` The right code is `+ obj[i].value); };` without the ')' bracket. I have tested it. It works fine with your data.

Comment: Still not working.  Could you please post your working example on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want something like this:

<strike>$.each(results, function(key, value) { 
      $("#tabs").tabs("add","tabs.aspx?tab=" + key,value)
    });</strike>

```
$.each(results, function(i) { 
    $("#tabs").tabs("add","tabs.aspx?tab=" + results[i].key, results[i].value)
});
```

If the content type of the response is "text/json" then you don't need to use parseJson() because JQuery will do that for you.

Comment: Best answer, but look into using `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.ajax()` (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: @oshirowanen: edited my answer so that it works for the json string you provided.

Answer (score 0):

When you return **properly** formed json (You can verify that it is properly formed here [Json Parser Online](http://json.parser.online.fr/)).  You can use the eval() function supplied by javascript. Ie.

```
var myJSONObject = {"bindings": [
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "deleteURI", "regex": "^delete.*"},
        {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "randomURI", "regex": "^random.*"}
    ]
};
```

To use a returned text string... do this:

```
var myObject = eval('(' + myJSONtext + ')');
```

If you insist on using the jquery parsing options, use:

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( myJsontext );
```

This info is available at [JSON in JavaScript](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Comment: I thought eval was evil?  Am I not supposed to use jqueries built in json methods instead of javascripts eval?

Comment: why is eval "evil"? remember jquery is javascript just using built-in helpers.

Comment: Eval **is** evil. You should be using `$.getJSON()` instead of `$.ajax()`

Comment: Yeah it's bad if your taking json from a query string or some other untrusted source since it can be used to run malicious code, but if your taking it from an ajax call I see absolutely no reason why you shouldn't use eval(), yes it may be a little slower, but unless hes returning 50 tabs, the performance difference is unnoticeable.